# Как засунуть конфигурацию nginx внутрь docker контейнера?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, docker

Господа,

я пытаюсь разобраться, как пользоваться nginx, установленным при помощи docker.

Устанавливаю из официального docker образа.

Конфигурация nginx у меня довольно простая: это просто несколько файлов, находящихся в /etc/nginx/sites-available, каждый из которых соответствует одному сайту, и выглядит примерно так:

```
      server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name site1.ru www.site1.ru;

        location / {
                #auth_basic           "Administrator’s Area";
                #auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/passwds/.htpasswd;
                proxy_redirect          http://192.168.0.101/  /; #<-- change
                proxy_pass_header       Server;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header        X-Scheme $scheme;
                proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header        X-NginX-Proxy true;
                proxy_connect_timeout   5;
                proxy_read_timeout      240;
                proxy_intercept_errors  on;

                proxy_pass              http://192.168.0.101/;  
        }
      }
```

Когда я запускаю эту конфигурацию в обычном nginx, всё работает. То есть, proxy-redirect нормально проксирует сайт.

Потом я создаю пару директорий

`~/nginx_cnf/etc_nginx_sites-available`

и

`~/nginx_cnf/etc_nginx_sites-enabled`

и копирую в них эти файлы конфигурации каждого конкретного сайта

А потом я пытаюсь перенести эту конфигурацию в nginx, запущенный в докер, командой

```
    docker run --name nginx1 -p 80:80 -v ~/nginx_cnf/etc_nginx_sites-available:/etc/nginx/sites-available -v ~/nginx_cnf/etc_nginx_sites-enabled:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled -d nginx
```

Но, к сожалению, nginx продолжает показывать дефолтную страницу. Что особенно странно, так как дефолтной конфигурации в моих файлах нет.

В логах, доступных по docker logs nginx1 - ничего особенного, они ничем не отличаются от дефолтного запуска nginx.

Не могли бы Вы подсказать мне, в какую сторону копать?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже, ответ нашелся вот в таком месте:
https://github.com/vfarcic/continuous-deployment/issues/2

Там указывается, что хостовый фолдер с конфиг-файлами типа `sites-available` надо мапить на фолдер /etc/nginx/conf.d

команда становится

```
    docker run --name nginx1 -p 80:80 -v ~/nginx_cnf/etc_nginx_sites-available:/etc/nginx/conf.d -d nginx
```

Это не решило моей проблемы, редирект по прежнему не работает, но, по крайней мере, nginx перестал показывать дефолтную страницу.
Теперь осталось понять, почему не работает прокси.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что `sites-available` загружаются в раздел http,

```
http {
    include sites-available/*.conf;
}
```

А `conf.d` загружается в корень конфига, а значит надо там написать:

```
http {
    server {
        location / {  }
    }
}
```

Я бы рекомендовал перемапить всю папку nginx и организовать как нравится.

Comment: Спасибо, очень классно, что есть новая идея. Сейчас попробую!

Comment: @S.H. перепиши всю папку с конфигами